# Vertical UINavigationBar in iPad application

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I am developing an iPad application and I would like to have a vertical `UINavigationBar` ( in the left of my view), is this possible to do? How I can i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean a UINavigationBar (with the typical "Back" button and a title), or a TabBar similar to one of the Facebook app for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, instead you can use `UIImage` with same look like `UINavigationBar` and Button and place them vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about one similar to the one tweetbot implements. If so you're going to have to create your own using images & a view, or rotate your navigation bar. Or you can check [FSVerticalTabBarController](https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController) and edit it to your needs.

[image]

Comment: I know you want a navigation bar and not a tab bar, but i'm sure you can edit the code in the project i provided to fit your needs. Good luck!